# InvalidDefinition Exception : Joda date/time type `org.joda.time.DateTime` not supported by default for S3event notification toJson method

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jackson

I have a Lambda which is triggered with S3 event source and my Lambda Handler is something like this.

```
public class S3RequestHandler {
     public void handleRequest (@NonNull final S3EventNotification notification) { 
          log.info(notification.toJson());
          //another method to process s3records
          processS3records(notification.getRecords());
     }
}
```

This throws the following exception below

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Joda date/time type
`org.joda.time.DateTime` not supported by default: add Module
"com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda" to enable handling (through reference
chain:com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification["Records"]>java.util.ArrayList[0]>com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification$S3EventNotificationRecord["eventTime"]): java.lang.IllegalStateException


java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Joda date/time type
`org.joda.time.DateTime` not supported by default: add Module
"com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda" to enable handling (through reference
chain: com.amazonaws.services.s3.event.S3EventNotification["Records"]>java.util.ArrayList[0]>com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.models.s3.S3EventNotification$S3EventNotificationRecord["eventTime"])
```

I have seen some posts which suggest registering jodamodule to object mapper but I am not using any object mappers in my case. the .toJson() method is declared in S3EventNotification class which should work out of the box  (I'm not sure about this one)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.